# Why is the JQuery dialog box moving after the first click?

Tags: jquery, dialog, popup

I finally got the dialog box positioned how I want it and it opens correctly on first click but then if you click another node it moves to a different position.

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajaisle/mc7p92z6/)

```
function click(link) {

        $("#dialog").html('<iframe src="http://www.'+link+'.com" style="height: 100vh"></iframe>').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     modal: true,

     position: { my: "right", at: "top", of: $("#Box3") },
  });

  $("#dialog").dialog('open');

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
.ui-dialog{position:fixed;}
```

> For further reference: [jquery/dialog](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)